# Converting a large String into a Dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I've a large String looking like this : '2002 | 09| 90|NUMBER|SALE|CLIENT \n 2002 | 39| 96|4958|100|James ...'  split by "|" and "\n". the size of each line is the same, what's the best way to turn this into a dataframe looking like this :

```
2002  09  90 NUMBER SALE  CLIENT

2002  39  96 4958   100   James
```

.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object to the [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) method to get the desired result. Example,

**Try this:**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO("""'2002 | 09| 90|NUMBER|SALE|CLIENT \n 2002 | 39| 96|4958|100|James """)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=r"\s*\|\s*")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   2002  09  90  NUMBER  SALE CLIENT
0  2002  39  96    4958   100  James
```

---

UPDATE (As per your requirements discussed in comments):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

data = StringIO("""Start Date str_date B N C \n Calculation notional cal_nt C B R\n price of today price_of_today N B R \n""")

lines = []
for line in data:
    line = line.strip()
    line = re.search(r"^(.*)\s(.*?\s.*?\s.*?\s.*?)$", line)
    grp1 = line.group(1)
    grp2 = line.group(2)
    line = "|".join([grp1, "|".join(grp2.split(" "))])
    lines.append(line)

data = StringIO("\n".join(lines))

columns = ["header1", "header2", "header3", "header4", "header5"]
df = pd.read_csv(data, names=columns,  sep=r"\s*\|\s*")
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, Is it possible to put header from an outside list ? I have a list with headers names can I add it to the dataframe ?

Comment: you have to provide an extra argument `names` to `read_csv` method like this `pd.read_csv(data, names=columns,  sep=r"\s*\|\s*")` where `columns` is the list of header names.

Comment: I have also this problem ' Start Date str_date B N C \n Calculation notional cal_nt C B R\n ....'

the issue is that I can't use one space or two to split my string because from Start date to str_date theres 2spaces but in the next line there will be 3 for example and maybe the next line will have 1space to seperate ... this makes it very hard to create a correct DataFrame as I want, is there a way to this ? thanks

Comment: To create a proper dataframe you've to make sure that all the dataitems in the string are separated by the proper separator, otherwise `read_csv` wont recognize them.

Comment: so there's no way to do this ?

Comment: can you show me the string you are dealing with? So, may be i can think a way out..

Comment: yes please, my string is large but looks like this : 'Start Date  str_date B N C \n Calculation notional 
   cal_nt C B R\n price of today   price_of_today N B R \n....'  there should be 5 columns at the end

Comment: Could you open another question so that i can properly provide the answer?

Comment: if you have an idea please share it with me its a bit urgent

Comment: You've to read the text line by line and use regular expressions to normalize each line so that all the columns are separated by `|`.

Comment: it didnt work, I got different result from what I expected because the last part of each line in string can be like this N R B or 10 N F or 0 F 10 ... we can drop that part of string also it's not very important

Comment: its length always is 8 is there a way to drop those last 8 caracteres ?